# Is the Global.Application_Start no longer used in Sitefinity 11.2?

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity

My `application_start` method in the Global.asax.cs file is never run.

I can reproduce this in a stock Sitefinity site created using the 11.2 Project Manager. If I add a Global.asax.cs file to it using Visual Studio, the events I define are never run.

Ultimately I'm just trying to register a custom configuration type in a project I'm upgrading to 11.2.

After an upgrade from 9.2 to 11.2, the code in Global.asax.cs is no longer running. I can put simple logging code in the `Application_Start` method and it will never get called. I have tried using `Debugger.Break()`, I've tried manual breakpoints, I've tried IIS and IISExpress. None of them work.

I think something in Sitefinity 11.2 hijacks the standard application startup, and therefore it never runs this pretty standard method, but I don't know why or how to circumvent this.

I found this question asked many years ago: [Global.asax not firing on precompiled Sitefinity project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160711/global-asax-not-firing-on-precompiled-sitefinity-project), but there is no answer.

I tried what the two comments suggested, but they do not apply to me since this isn't a deployed site, it is in my development environment.

Here is my Global.asax.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Telerik.Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Abstractions;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration;
using SitefinityWebApp.Custom.Configuration;

namespace SitefinityWebApp
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            throw new Exception("I told you this wouldn't run.");

            logStartUpCall(string.Concat("Application started at: ", DateTime.Now));

            Bootstrapper.Bootstrapped += Bootstrapper_Bootstrapped;
            Bootstrapper.Initialized += this.Bootstrapper_Initialized;

            //log call
            logStartUpCall(string.Concat("Call made to bootstrapper: ", DateTime.Now));
        }


        void Bootstrapper_Initialized(object sender, Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ExecutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //log call
            logStartUpCall(string.Concat("Bootstrapper_Initialized:", " ", DateTime.Now));


            if (e.CommandName == "Bootstrapped")
            {
                ObjectFactory.Container.RegisterType<Telerik.Sitefinity.Workflow.IWorkflowDefinitionResolver, Nccer.Sitefinity.CustomWorkflowDefinitionResolver>();

                System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.MapRoute(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes,
                    "Classic",
                    "Redirect",
                    new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index" });

                Config.RegisterSection<MercuryConfiguration>();
            }

            //log call
            logStartUpCall(string.Concat("Bootstrapper Configuration & Registration complete:", " ", DateTime.Now));
        }

        protected void Bootstrapper_Bootstrapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            logStartUpCall(string.Concat("Bootstrapper_Bootstrapped:", " ", DateTime.Now));

            Nccer.Sitefinity.FeatherActionInvokerCustom.Register();

            logStartUpCall(string.Concat("Bootstrapper_Bootstrapped finished:", " ", DateTime.Now));
        }

        protected void logStartUpCall(string message)
        {

            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/App_Data/SiteFinity/Logs/Startup.log"), true);

            // write a line of text to the file
            tw.WriteLine(message);

            // close the stream
            tw.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the `application_start` method to be called, but it is not. The exception is not thrown, the logging is not done, the module is not registered. Its like it isn't even there.

I've been working on this for the better part of the day and I'm at a loss.

Comment: I have a site on 11.2.6925 version and Application_Start is fired as expected. Did you actually rebuild the project after adding the Global.asax files? Are you in Debug mode?

Comment: Also, any errors in the log files?